# full width navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I need to boorstrap `full width navbar` in `940px` container and after `header` like this pic. How to ?

[image]

Code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w6PY/)

Comment: What's your code look like up to this point?

Comment: Container is what restricts your navigation bar to 960px.

Comment: @brbcoding: Code in http://jsfiddle.net/4w6PY/

Comment: Gotcha -- left an answer down below with the proper bootstrap classes and styling.

Comment: @brbcoding: how to show navbar text in `center(940px)` container?!

Comment: @B.BKing updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would do it in a "bootstrappy" way...

```
/* put the stuff you want NOT to span 100% in a container */
<div class="container">
  /* wrap the grouping in a row */
  <div class="row">
    /* left center and right classes are unneeded.*/
    /* Just used to show color in the fiddle */
    <div class="span3 left">Header Left</div>
    <div class="span6 center">Header Center</div>
    <div class="span3 right">Header Right</div>
  </div>
</div>

/* navbar outside the container will span 100% */
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="span12">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* back into a container so it doesn't span the full width */
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://cdpn.io/Bqflo)**

EDIT: Updated to reflect requirements of navlinks inside container.

Comment: This Worked! But Not Show Navbar Title And home/Link ... in Center.

Comment: Yeah, just wrap the contents in a container (not the whole navbar, just the content).

Comment: What's not working? It's working exactly like your picture. http://i.imgur.com/an62Zbj.png

Comment: Yep, don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Must be a browser specific problem. Works fine for me in webkit and moz. This is the way to handle it, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You need a container, to hold the header and the content. 
For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="headerleft"></div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="headerright"></div>
</div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS would be similar to this:

```
.container { width: 75%; }
#nav { width: 100%; }
```